# Transfer of UTM tags from Google ads to the android application

Tags: android, ads, google-ads-api

The install referrer library is installed in my application. Through it, I get where the user came from, respectively.
I want to receive the static parameter utm_source = alexander if the user has installed the application by advertising launched in Google Ads UAC.
I try to set the final url suffix at the account setup level - "referrer = utm_source% 3Dalexander".
But I get "utm_source = (not set)" instead of the given parameter.

But if I go directly to the link "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...&referrer=utm_source%3DAlexander", then everything works as it should and in the statistics I see - "utm_source = Alexander ".

Can you please tell me how you can configure Google UAC correctly so that the static parameter specified in advance is passed to the application?

P.S. Auto-tagging is disabled at the account level in the settings